# How count active connection postgresql (without idle) for every database?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jconsole

[Image org.apatche.commons.pool2. Show numActive connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4qEy.png)

I have many connection from java server application.

How get numActive connection (like jconsole) on PostgreSQL server?
Thanks

Comment: That is that table that you've to look at, I don't know the reason why you ask the question?

Comment: Sorry, i learning yet.

Comment: I updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
SELECT datname, count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity
  WHERE state != 'idle' GROUP BY datname;
```

Is that what you're looking for? It seems from your question like there is something else going on, but without more detail it's impossible to say.